# How to calculate how much to add so that buying 1 expensive item is better than 10 cheap items

Tags: education

I am trying to make a shop for self learning but i have a small hiccup!

I have this list of items that has a USD value assigned to it. But I want to make it so if they buy a "100 GB/s" it should be cheaper than buying 100 "1 GB/s" or 10 "10 GB/s". I have been trying for ages but i can't seem to figure it out.

Currently if they buy 100 of "1 GB/s" it will cost $7200 which is the value of one "100 GB/s"

If I'm unclear please write down below so I can explain further.

How do I do it?

```
100 MB/s = $8
200 MB/s = $14
300 MB/s = $22
400 MB/s = $29
500 MB/s = $36
600 MB/s = $43
700 MB/s = $50
800 MB/s = $58
900 MB/s = $65
1 GB/s = $72
2 GB/s = $144 
3 GB/s = $216
4 GB/s = $288
5 GB/s = $360
6 GB/s = $432
7 GB/s = $504
8 GB/s = $576
9 GB/s = $648
10 GB/s = $720
11 GB/s = $792
12 GB/s = $864
13 GB/s = $936
14 GB/s = $1008
15 GB/s = $1080
20 GB/s = $1440
25 GB/s = $1800
30 GB/s = $2160
35 GB/s = $2520
40 GB/s = $2880
45 GB/s = $3240
50 GB/s = $3600
60 GB/s = $4320
70 GB/s = $5040
80 GB/s = $5760
90 GB/s = $6480
100 GB/s = $7200
```

Comment: What happens if you simply decrease the price for 100GB/s ???

Comment: You want the cost per GB to be a non-increasing function of the amount of GB per unit.

Comment: But if i decrease 100 GB/s with like 200 how much do I decrease all the other?, if i decrease all with 200 it's basically the same problem but lower price.

Comment: First pick the cost per GB vs. amount of GB per unit curve.

Comment: copper.hat , could you explain that a little more, I don't understand. What is the "unit curve"?

Comment: You have a collection of objects labelled $n$ B/s. For each object compute the cost per B/s, call it $c(n)$. You want to have $c(n)$ be a non-increasing function of $n$. Then price the smallest $n$ and work from there (or the other way around, if you prefer).

Comment: (Not 'unit curve', it was the curve generated by cost per B/s vs. the amount of B/s.)

Comment: I'm sorry, that is just too advanced for my math with c(n) and stuff. Is there any other way to explain it?

Comment: Its just division.

Comment: Ok, I think it's just the fancy words that's messing with me

Comment: @Heinz The way I'd set this up is to have price as a function of $x\,GB$, such that $\mathrm{price}(n\cdot x)<n\cdot\mathrm{price}(x)$. What I mean by this is that the price of buying $n\cdot x$ GB is less than buying $x$ GB but $n$ times over. For example if $n=2$, you want $\mathrm{price}(2x)$ (buying double) to be cheaper than $2\mathrm{price}(x)$ (buying it twice). A function that comes to mind is $\mathrm{price}(x)=\log(x)$ but you'd probably need some tweaking to make sure you're not losing money. I'm not saying this is the best or easiest way, it's just how I'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to arrange that the unit price $p_N$ falls by a certain fraction $f$ when the quantity $N$ increases tenfold. This is a property of the function
$$
p_N = p_1 N^{-k}
$$
where $p_1$ is the price of one unit sold individually and $k$ is a constant.

$k$ is found by setting
$$
10^{-k} = 1 - f
$$
which gives
$$
k = -\log_{10}{(1-f)}
$$

**Example**

$p_1 = \$72$ (the price of 1Gb/s)

$f=0.1$ (the unit price is reduced by 10% price for a tenfold increase in quantity)

With this data we find
$$
k = -\log_{10}{(1-f)} = -\log_{10}{0.9} = 0.045757
$$

The unit price of a sale of 3Gb/s (N=3) is then
$$
p_3 = p_1 3^{-k} = 72 \times 3^{-0.045757} = \$68.47005
$$
and the cost to the customer is
$$
3 p_3 = 3\times 68.47005 = 205.41
$$

As expected, the cost of 10Gb/s $(N=10)$ works out at \$648.00 (90% of \$720).